# Apache2 is not wanting to be deleted

Tags: apache2

I am having trouble removing a VirtualHost, so I thought of just simply editing the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file. It turns out that I am trying to add the original 'index.html' file, which I have in the /var/www/ directory. But it is not working because another VirtualHost has taken port 80 and I don't see my 'index.html' file listed there in the default file. I am super frustrated, so I am thinking of just doing a fresh install of the apache2 service. But even though I use this command to remove it:

```
 sudo apt-get install --remove apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Even though I do this, it is not removed and I get this error at the end of the process:

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  libopenvnc-imgproc2.3
  libavfilter2:armhf
  libav-tools
  ffmpeg
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there any way to do a fresh install of apache2 along with php5 and libapache2-mod-php5 as I had installed them when I first got my Pi? I am just lost, I have gone to a million forums and none have helped me.....

Here is the 'default' file text:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:8091
 NameVirtualHost *:80
 NameVirtualHost *:443
```

## This is what I tried doing, but it didn't work, it said the file couldn't be found!

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/remote_replay.php 
ServerName 192.168.1.80  
 </VirtualHost>
```

## This part below works fine, but I want it removed!!!!!

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess web2py user=www-data group=www-data

 <VirtualHost *:8091>
 WSGIProcessGroup web2py
 WSGIScriptAlias / /home/www-data/web2py/wsgihandler.py
 WSGIPassAuthorization On

 <Directory /home/www-data/web2py>
 AllowOverride None
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 <Files wsgihandler.py>
  Allow from all
 </Files>
 </Directory>

 AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(?:_[\d]+.[\d]+.[\d]+/)?(.*) \
       /home/www-data/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2
 <Directory /home/www-data/web2py/applications/*/static/>
 Options -Indexes
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from all
 </Directory>

 <Location /admin>
 Deny from all
 </Location>

 <LocationMatch ^/([^/]+)/appadmin>
 Deny from all
 </LocationMatch>

 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.cert
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/self_signed.key

 WSGIProcessGroup web2py
 WSGIScriptAlias / /home/www-data/web2py/wsgihandler.py
 WSGIPassAuthorization On

 <Directory /home/www-data/web2py>
 AllowOverride None
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 <Files wsgihandler.py>
  Allow from all
 </Files>
 </Directory>

 AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(?:_[\d]+.[\d]+.[\d]+/)?(.*) \
    /home/www-data/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2

 <Directory /home/www-data/web2py/applications/*/static/>
 Options -Indexes
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from all
 </Directory>

 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your virtual host configuration, `DocumentRoot` must be a directory.  If you want to serve a specific file, use `DocumentIndex` to specify the files to use in order of preference:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  DocumentIndex remote_replay.php index.php index.html index.htm
  ServerName 192.168.1.80  
</VirtualHost>
```